# Why is it in TV shows and Movies you never see logos of main stream stores?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property

Why is it in TV shows and movies you never see popular chains, like McDonald's or Starbucks? I'm assuming it has to do with Copyright. If something does show a brand, does the band pay them or does the maker pay the brand? For example I remember seeing a Spiderman TV show where they had the Starbucks logo in it. Did the producers pay Starbucks for the right to use their logo, or did Starbucks pay the producers for the publicity?

Comment: Duplicate? http://law.stackexchange.com/q/56/84

Comment: I've wondered that a lot too. Like for Apple Computers, you see their computers in police offices every time you in one on TV. I've been in police offices enough to know that in real life, they are all Dells. Apple obviously paid them

Comment: I think this would be more on topic at [movies.se].  The legal component of this question was addressed in http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/56/is-there-a-legal-reason-why-fictional-shows-use-imitation-brand-names

Answer (score -1):

To my understanding its.....

## Money.

Studios often want dollars to include brand products in their productions (since it's advertising).

Brands often want money to use their products in a production (protecting their copyrights).

It's a vicious money-hungry circle. There's really no way to tell which is which without being privy to the details of a specific production.

Comment: On the contrary, brands regard prominent product placement in a tv show or movie as advertising. Do you have any source showing that they charge for this? My understanding is rather the opposite: that they *pay* for it.

Comment: Cursory search: [See #3 under "Product Placement" here](http://www.marklitwak.com/movie-merchandising.html) -- Brands **do** spend money to promote a movie in some deals.

Comment: "Nabisco paid $100,000 to have its Baby Ruth candy bar shown in The Goonies." this is the opposite of what you've stated in your answer: "Brands often want money to use their products in a production (protecting their copyrights)."

Comment: @phoog perhaps you missed the part of this answer where I stated **both** are possible. I didn't **not** state that there was only one option. Really unclear why you feel this point needs to argued. Add your own answer if you disagree with mine. Additionally.. you can find several companies suing films [here](http://www.indieclear.com/resources/film-lawsuits) some of which are related to unauthorized product use.